# How do you convert a GIF to a PNG and remove its transparency with GD in PHP?

Tags: php, html, png, gd, gif

Is there a way to convert a GIF to a PNG and remove its transparency with GD in PHP?

Comment: `imagepng(imagecreatefromgif('x.gif'), 'x.png')`

Comment: @MarcB: will the original matte color be preserved, or will the image default to white where there was transparency in the original GIF?

Comment: gd by default will not preserve transparency, so dumping a gif->png should produce a png with black holes wherever the gif was transparent. or maybe just with the actual color that was marked as the transparent one. remember, gif's transparency is just "wherever color #X is used, don't draw the image". it's not real transparency. the color exists and is visible in the .gif, just not drawn.